# Error con la api de google driver

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive

Tengo la siguiente situación, estoy usando la **API** de **Google Driver** desde mi **php** para subir ficheros desde mi sistema. Lo que me esta sucediendo, es que me genera un error de permiso a la hora de ejecutar el **script** cuando voy a subir el fichero. Verifique mi **token** y me dice que no a expirado aun. A continuación les dejo el error, el resultado del token y código que estoy usando para ver si me pueden ayudar.

Gracias.

**Token**

```
{
  "issued_to": "569124525622-smkdbucj6bj8t87ptisvd2sdma3v747o.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  "audience": "569124525622-smkdbucj6bj8t87ptisvd2sdma3v747o.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly",
  "expires_in": 1512,
  "access_type": "offline"
}
```

**Error que se genera**

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with
>   message ' in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/gdriver/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Http/REST.php
>   on line 118
>
> Google_Service_Exception: { "error": { "errors": [ { "domain":
>   "global", "reason": "insufficientPermissions", "message":
>   "Insufficient Permission" } ], "code": 403, "message": "Insufficient
>   Permission" } } in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/gdriver/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Http/REST.php
>   on line 118

**Mi código**

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
$client = getClient();
$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
$fileMetadata = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(array(
    'name' => 'sql_query.jpg'));
$content = file_get_contents('files/sql_query.jpg');
$file = $service->files->create($fileMetadata, array(
    'data' => $content,
    'mimeType' => 'image/jpeg',
    'uploadType' => 'multipart',
    'fields' => 'id'));
printf("File ID: %s\n", $file->id);
```

Comment: Como dice @Sr1871, tienes que darle un scope (permiso) para poder crear archivos. Eso se hace mediante el método `setScopes`, debes hacerlo tan pronto creas el cliente: **`$client->setScopes(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE);`** [Aquí puedes ver el alcance de cada scope](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/php/latest/class-Google_Service_Drive.html). Sé cuidadoso con los permisos que otorgas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás pasando un scope incorrecto, según la [documentación](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create), para crear usar `create` en `files` necesitas al menos uno de estos scope

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata
```

Tú incluso estás pasando scopes de solo lectura, añade alguno de esos scope a tu `client`

Answer (score 0):

En modo desarrollo uso todos estos scopes para no tener problemas:

```
const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata',
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file',
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata',
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly',
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.photos.readonly',
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly',
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.scripts',
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.activity',
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.activity.readonly'];
```

Estoy trabajando en un CRUD con google drive en NESTjs y hasta el momento todo ok.